# Force emacs to use Texlive 2012 instead of 2009

Tags: ubuntu, emacs

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 with Emacs 23.3.1 for handling .tex files. The default installation of Texlive in Ubuntu is version 2009, and I just upgraded to Texlive 2012: in my /usr/local/texlive directory, I can see the 2012 folder containing the files for the latest version. Also there is a folder called "texmf-local" which I believe is for texlive 2009.

My question is: when I use emacs to open a .tex file and pdflatex it, it produces error, from which (after C-c C-l to see the error output) I realized that **emacs is still using Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)**. How can I **force emacs to handle .tex files by the latest texlive 2012 instead of 2009**? Do I need to edit the .emacs file or there are other ways to change the setting?

I appreciate your kindly help!

Comment: what is the output of `pdflatex --version` and `which pdflatex`?  I would make sure that the version of Texlive you want is first in the path before digging into emacs.  If you don't need Texlive 2009 for anything else, uninstall it.

Comment: @tcaswell: Thanks for your reply! It shows: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian), and /usr/bin/pdflatex. How can I uninstall Texlive 2009? Is that possible using SSynaptic Pkg Manager? Thanks again!

Comment: You should be able to use the package manager to remove it.  Failing that `sudo apt-get remove texlive`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to adjust your `PATH` environment variable and put your texlive 2012 directory first.  This could be either done by modifying your shell setup, so Emacs will pickup modified `PATH`, or you can change it from Emacs with command (change path accordingly to your setup - I don't remember right now how TeXLive organizes bin directories):

```
(setenv "PATH" (concat "/usr/local/texlive/bin/:" (getenv "PATH")))
```

Just put this line in your `~/.emacs` file...

Comment: thank you for your reply, @Alex! Would you be a little more specific on changing the path? I am a newbie in unix so I am not sure how to proceed...

Comment: instead of `/usr/local/texlive/bin` you need to put full path to `pdflatex` binary from TeXLive distribution, for example, on my Mac OS X it was `/usr/local/texlive/2008/bin/universal-darwin/` - I don't have TeXLive installed right now